# Can you nest a MAXIFS function into an IF ArrayFormula to copy the formula down a column?

Tags: google-sheets

I currently have a Google Sheet that is running the following function:

```
={"Internal Links";ArrayFormula(IF(A2:A="","",MAXIFS(AHREFS!G:G,AHREFS!I:I,A2:A)))}
```

This function is meant to do the following:

1. Is the cell in column A of the "Aggregate" tab blank
2. If so, add a "0" in column L of the "Aggregate" tab
3. If not, check cell in column A of the "Aggregate" tab and see if exists in the datasource "AHREFS" tab column I
4. If the contents of column A in the "Aggregate" tab do not exist in the "AHREFS" tab column I add a "0" to column L of the "Aggregate" tab
5. Otherwise, collect the MAX value in the "AHREFS" tab under column G and add it to the "Aggregate" tab column L

What it doesn't do:

- Copy the formula down the entirety of the "Aggregate" tab column L

Here is a link to the working Google Sheet:
https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1iHkU-rNtNhoOKvW_CWY7WU5OLsMFVqEFNRZlx_R-7RY/edit#gid=0

Please Advise!

Comment: MAXIFS() does not work in Arrayformula.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Two problems.

1. your links on "aggregate" end with a "/" while the links on "AHREFS" do not.
2. you cannot use MAXIFS() in an arrayformula.  But you can do a vlookup into a query like this.  Which I have implemented in cell L1 on a new tab called MK.Help

Note: I've avoided the "/" problem by adding a "/" to the AHref values within the formula and adding a wildcard "*" to the lookup values within the formula.

```
={"Internal Links";ArrayFormula(IF(A2:A="","",VLOOKUP(A2:A&"*",QUERY({AHREFS!G:G,AHREFS!I:I&"/"},"select Col2,MAX(Col1) group by Col2"),2,0)))}
```